# Negative index Sobolev spaces, properties

Tags: fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

I was hoping to find some references for the following facts:

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain with smooth boundary in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

(i) If $\nabla p$ is a distribution in $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ then $p \in L^2(\Omega)$.

(ii) Following two characterizations of $H^{-s}$ are equivalent: First is by taking the Fourier transform in distribution sense and consider the integral $\int (1+|\xi|^2)^{-s}|\hat{f}(\xi)|^2$, second is to take the dual of $H^s$ and consider the operator norm.

(iii) Spaces $H^{-s}$ are invariant under the action of a diffeomorphism on the space.

Comment: I don't know how you can define $H^s$ spaces on a bounded domain via Fourier transform. That approach works on the free space, or on the torus, where Fourier transform is available.